# SQL OR Operator on different tables and column names

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know that I can use the OR SQL operator on the same column of a table like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name = 'Peter' OR last_name = 'Smith';
```

But the situation I have right now is that I'm trying to use the OR operator on two different tables (different column names). Is that possible? How can I achieve that in an SQL query?

And yes there is a foreign key column that links one table to the primary key column of the other table.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are those two tables having any relationship

Comment: please add table structure

Comment: 2500 rep and you should know that there is not enough information in your question.

Comment: No need of asking these types of silly questions here. And also you will get so many answers for these types of questions in google. Just google it.

Answer (score 1):

If the fields in the different tables have the same name, you can distinguish them with `tablename.fieldname`, if the tables have the same name (in different schemas), you can further qualify the names with `schemaname.tablename.fieldname`.

Of course, all tables referenced in the `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses should be included in the `FROM` clause.

Note: If a table is aliased in the `FROM`, the alias should be used instead of the table name.

---

You cannot display (or use in WHERE conditions, etc...) fields from a table that not included in the `FROM`; however, you can use subqueries on those tables.

Examples:

```
...
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE t1.field1 = somevalue 
   OR EXISTS (
         SELECT * 
         FROM table2 AS t2 
         WHERE t2.somefield = someothervalue
   )
...
```

or

```
SELECT t1.field1
, (SELECT t2.somefield FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.anotherfield = somevalue LIMIT 1) AS t2Val
FROM table1 AS t1
```

...

Comment: Now let's say data is coming from ONE table and not the other, how do I, in one query display the fields of either table 1 OR table 2. Can I use the OR operator in the SELECT clause?

Comment: @user765368 see edit (stuff below separator in answer)

Comment: What if I want to return multiple fields from t2, I need to do multiple subqueries for that?

Comment: @user765368 Yes. Is there a reason you can't `JOIN` the tables?

Comment: The tables are joined through foreign key relationships. My problem is this, let's say I have table1 and table2. If I rung my query and that the records that this query should return are only in table2, if in my SELECT I have fields from table1, the query returns EMPTY. But if I just put SELECT *, it works, I don't get empty, but I'm afraid there would be a performance issue because my two tables have a lot of columns.

Comment: The query you have shown does not show any `JOIN` at all, just having a foreign key from one table to another does not automatically include the associated table in any query the other one is a part of. To get values from table2 in a query, table2 must be explicitly included in that query.

Comment: or to put it another way, foreign key relationships do not `JOIN` tables, they create a constraint that requires values entered into a field correspond to values that exist in another field.

Comment: I know how to join queries, the query that you see in my question was, as stated, just an example of how OR is used in a query. It has nothing to do with the second part of the question that describes the actual problem. I will just use " SELECT * " and problem solved.

Comment: If you only want some fields from t1 and all fields from t2, you can `SELECT t1.fieldX, t1.fieldY, t2.*`; though I am still not sure how any of this relates to `OR`

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible

```
SELECT users.* FROM users,countries WHERE users.last_name = 'Peter' OR countries.name = 'mexico' AND users.idCountry=countries.id;
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that this would be correct since there is no proper join on the FK. `And yes there is a foreign key column that links one table to the primary key column of the other table.`

Comment: Just wanted to know if it was possible to use the OR operator with different tables and the answer is YES. However to view a query where foreign keys are used here is one `SELECT users.* FROM users,countries WHERE users.last_name = 'Peter' AND countries.id = users.countryId`